# Renaming files to their foldername

Tags: python, macos, perl, renaming

Helo there.

I have a Movies folder with subfolders inside. 
In those subfolders (which is the name of the movie) are the actual movie files which I would like to rename from `somename.nfo` to `subfoldername.release` and from `somename.mkv` to `subfoldername.mkv`.
Folderstructure is like this:
complete/La.Haine.1995.1080p.BluRay.DTS.x264-DON/lh-don.mkv
complete/La.Haine.1995.1080p.BluRay.DTS.x264-DON/lh-don.nfo
and would like to **automagically** rename it to this:
complete/La.Haine.1995.1080p.BluRay.DTS.x264-DON/La.Haine.1995.1080p.BluRay.DTS.x264-DON.mkv
complete/La.Haine.1995.1080p.BluRay.DTS.x264-DON/La.Haine.1995.1080p.BluRay.DTS.x264-DON.release

My library is on Mac OS with Perl and Python on it. I can easily adapt any script, but need some guidance on how to set and read the foldername as some kind of variable.

All guidance is welcome :-) 
Thank you for reading.

Comment: Maybe we do it the other way round: You try it, we adapt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example in perl.

You'll probably want to modify this, but it shows how to use opendir/readdir which is what you need I think. It could be made much shorter but probably not as good looking as that python version so I went for verbose and (hopefully) clear :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
use warnings;
use strict;

my $rootdir = 'your/root/dir';
opendir( my $rootdh, $rootdir ) || die;
foreach my $dir ( readdir $rootdh ) {
    # skip over the special directories . and ..
    if ($dir =~ m/^\./) {
        next;
    }
    # only want directories
    next unless ( -d "$rootdir/$dir" );
    opendir( my $dh, "$rootdir/$dir" ) || die;
    foreach my $file ( readdir $dh ) {
        if ($file =~ m/^\./) {
            next;
        }
        # only want files this time
        next unless ( -f "$rootdir/$dir/$file" );
        my $extension = $file;
        $extension =~ s/.*\.//g;
        print "$rootdir/$dir/$file", " will be renamed to: ", "$rootdir/$dir/$dir.$extension", "\n";
        # uncomment this when you're ready!
        #rename "$rootdir/$dir/$file" "$rootdir/$dir/$dir.$extension";
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked **perfectly**, it only lacked a `comma` in the rename line :-), now I need to figure something out to have extension nfo renamed to release.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you can use `glob.glob()` for this kind of thing.  But since you want to walk through folders recursively, you might want to use the `os.walk` and `fnmatch` combo instead:

```
import os
import fnmatch

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/start/dir/'):
  for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.mkv'):
    # do your rename here
```